# RE: TKinter Table Row Deletion (PYTHON)

Tags: python, tkinter

(If anyone has seen my previous question, I found a way to save the row indexes and use them in the delete function :3)

Is there a way to stop/delete a running function/table on a button click? I am making a simple customer registration program which saves data from text fields (`cID`, `custName`, `custEmail`, and `custBday`) and deletes a selected row. My problem is that whenever I delete a row, the last row somehow leaves/lags behind creating this duplicate whenever a row is deleted. Any suggestions or is there something I've done wrong or I've missed?

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

at = False
dotcom = False
list = [['ID', 'NAME', 'EMAIL', 'BIRTHDATE']]
recentIndex = []
ID = 1
storedIndex = 0


def callback(event):


    custid.config(state=NORMAL)
    custid.delete('1.0', END)
    custid.insert(1.0, list[event.widget._values][0])
    custid.config(state=DISABLED)

    cName.set(list[event.widget._values][1])
    cEmail.set(list[event.widget._values][2])
    birthdate.set(list[event.widget._values][3])
    indexPosition = event.widget._values
    recentIndex.append(indexPosition)
    print(recentIndex)

def createTable():
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list[0])):
            mgrid = tk.Entry(window, width = 10, bg= 'yellow')
            mgrid.insert(tk.END, list[i][j])
            mgrid._values= i
            mgrid.grid (row = i + 5,column = j + 5)
            mgrid.bind("<Button-1>", callback)


def delete():
    try:
        list.pop(recentIndex[-1])
        if recentIndex[-1] > 0 or NONE:
            msgbox("Data Delete", "Record")
            createTable()
        else:
            msgbox("No Data Selected", "record")
            return
    except:
        msgbox("No Data Selected", "record")

def save ():
    
        custid.config(state= NORMAL)
        initialValue = int(custid.get('1.0', END))
        custid.delete('1.0', END)
        list.append([ID, custName.get(), custEmail.get(), custBday.get()])
        custid.insert(1.0, initialValue + 1)
        custid.config(state=DISABLED)
        createTable()

        msgbox("Saved", "Record")


        ID = ID + 1


def msgbox (msg, titlebar):
    messagebox.showinfo(title = titlebar, message=msg)

def products():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Products Form")
    window.geometry("550x400")
    window.configure(bg="orange")



window = Tk()
window.title("Sample Window")
window.geometry("550x400")
window.configure(bg="orange")

menubar = Menu(window)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Products", command=products)
filemenu.add_command(label="Orders")
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command = window.quit)

window.config(menu=menubar)

labelTitle = Label(window, text="Customer Registration System", width=30, height=1, bg="yellow", anchor= "center")
labelTitle.config(font=("Courier", 10))
labelTitle.grid(column=2, row=1)

labelID = Label(window, text="Customer ID", width = 20, height = 1, bg = "yellow")
labelID.grid(column=1, row=2)

cID = StringVar()
custid = Text(window, width=15, height=1)
custid.grid(column=2, row=2)
custid.insert(1.0, "1")
custid.config(state = DISABLED)

labelNameCheck = Label(window, text="Last Name, First Name", width = 20, height = 1, bg = "yellow")
labelNameCheck.grid(column=3, row=3)
labelName = Label(window, text="Customer Name", width = 20, height = 1, bg = "yellow")
labelName.grid(column=1, row=3)

cName = StringVar()
custName = Entry(window, textvariable = cName)
custName.grid(column=2, row=3)

labelEmail = Label(window, text="Customer Email", width = 20, height = 1, bg = "yellow")
labelEmail.grid(column=1, row=4)


cEmail = StringVar()
custEmail = Entry(window, textvariable = cEmail)
custEmail.grid(column=2, row=4)
custEmail.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)

labelEmail = Label(window, text="[a-z]@[a-z].com", width = 20, height = 1, bg = "yellow")
labelEmail.grid(column=3, row=4)

labelBday = Label(window, text="Customer Birthdate", width = 20, height = 1, bg = "yellow")
labelBday.grid(column=1, row=5)

birthdate= StringVar()
custBday = Entry(window, textvariable = birthdate)
custBday.grid(column=2, row=5)
custBday.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyupBdate)


birthdateCheck = Label(window, text="mm/dd/yyyy", width = 20, height = 1, bg = "yellow")
birthdateCheck.grid(column=3, row=5)

savebtn = Button(text = "Save", command = save)
savebtn.grid(column=1)


deletebtn = Button(text = "Delete", command = delete)
deletebtn.grid(column=1)



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete current displayed records before showing updated records inside `createTable()`.  Also better create a frame for showing the records, so that it is more easier to clear the displayed records:

```py
def createTable():
    # clear current displayed records
    for w in tableFrame.winfo_children():
        w.destroy()
    # populate records
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list[0])):
            mgrid = tk.Entry(tableFrame, width = 10, bg= 'yellow')  # use tableFrame as parent
            mgrid.insert(tk.END, list[i][j])
            mgrid._values= i
            mgrid.grid (row = i,column = j)
            mgrid.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

...

# frame for showing records
tableFrame = Frame(window)
tableFrame.grid(row=5, column=5)

...
```

Comment: yeah thats what i've been trying to code for the past hour, sadly im to dumdum to figure it out, ive been trying to return the function at each delete press but no luck so far.